# Trying to identify a story which has trade missions to alien planets

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I am not certain but I believe this story was in an anthology with other stories about humans trading with alien civilizations.

The specific story I am looking for starts with an alien king waking up and his "god" reminds him its time to dredge the harbor. There's another scene where a tradesman consults with his "god" on a fair price for his goods.

Then there's a scene where the humans are sitting around talking and one of them says that the aliens are not actually sentient, that the "gods" they hear are actually some kind of highly advanced instinct.

Comment: It's a Harry Turtledove one. I think it's probably one of the ones in Earthgrip, but not having a copy handy, I can't figure out which one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, right author, wrong book.

It's [“Bluff”](https://turtledove.fandom.com/wiki/Bluff), from Kaleidoscope by Harry Turtledove. I don't know if it was in any other anthologies, but the two plot points you mention are definitely in there.

Comment: aye thats it, much obliged.