# Explorers find pre-industrial culture that is not conscious/self-aware

Tags: story-identification, first-contact

Looking for a story (maybe novelette or novella, not a novel), probably in Analog, probably in mid- to late-70's, in which extra-planetary explorers encounter a population that is intelligent but not conscious or self-aware.  Some parts of this society are starting to become conscious; I think it was traders, and maybe military, because they were most often confronted with new situations requiring creative thinking.  I was reminded of this when I read Julian Jaynes' "The Origins of Consciousness in the Breakdown of the Bicameral Mind."  The locals in the story were, as I remember it, precisely what Jaynes was writing about.

Comment: How is consciousness defined in the context of the story? How do the explorers determine that the natives are not conscious?

Comment: Peter Watts' book *Blindsight* has as a central plot point the difference between intelligence and self-awareness, but it clearly doesn't match otherwise.

Comment: It seems...strange, to say the least, to posit that people believe gods are telling the to do things, and then conclude that they are not conscious.

Comment: A similar situation was at the heart of the plot of Lloyd Biggle Jr's novel _The World Menders_ (Doubleday, 1971). There were two humanoid races or species on a planet, one group treated as slave labor by the other, and it took the human observers a long time to realize the subjugated group didn't even _think_ of themselves as "downtrodden slaves who yearn to be free" -- because they didn't have that much capacity for abstract thought in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most likely this is Bluff by Harry Turtledove

as answered here [Trying to identify a story which has trade missions to alien planets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43638/trying-to-identify-a-story-which-has-trade-missions-to-alien-planets)

Comment: Note that [this review says](http://turtledove.wikia.com/wiki/Bluff): *"Bluff" takes its inspiration from the work of Professor Julian Jaynes, whose 1976 work, The Origin of Consciousness in the Bicameral Mind first theorized that early man was not conscious, or self aware; rather, such a state of consciousness developed only gradually.*